# How can I create a while loop if a query goes over 10 minutes execution then it exits

Tags: sql, oracle, time, while-loop, execution

This is the actual query, so the refresh starts and then finishes usually in 30 seconds or less but now and then gets stuck.  I want it to end if it has elapsed more than 10 minutes.

```
select 'Refresh started: '||to_char(sysdate,'DD-Mon-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from      
dual;
DECLARE
  temp integer;
BEGIN
  temp := DBMS_DEFER_SYS.PUSH (
                     destination => 'some address',
                     stop_on_error => FALSE,
                     delay_seconds => 0,
                     parallelism => 0);
end;
/
select 'Refresh Ended: '|| to_char(sysdate, 'DD-Mon-YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from     
dual;
disc
```

It then continues on to the next query similar to the one above but connecting somewhere else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are multiple queries within the block, I want to end this query and then continue to the next query which runs after the first is done.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the actual code above so it makes more sense.

Comment: Are you using this for replication? There might be unfortunate consequences if you end a replication process before it is finished.

Comment: It is replication, I probably won't necessarily end the replication but email the DBA if the query has elapsed over a certain time.  I just said exit as an example, but really I would email DBA if the query has been running for over 10 minutes.  How can I put this?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2012.htm

Have a look at `ALTER SESSION TIMEOUT nsecs`  and see if that meets your needs.
It depends on what is causing the delay, which you do not seem to mention.

With a little more information it seems that you want a resource profile -
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF01310

Probably one where you specify:

```
CONNECT_TIME 
Specify the total elapsed time limit for a session, expressed in minutes.
```

Comment: The alter session timeout seems to be more for an error condition, the delay is very rare but does happen now and then, many times there might not be an error message that comes up (eg. No Ora error).  So I want the query to execute but want some timeout condition where if it goes over a certain time period (eg. 10 minutes) then an email is sent or is aborted.

Comment: It helped with more information.  You want a resource profile - edited the answer